# Why are cross products in different coordinates different?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, cross-product

For example:
In coordinate (1): $[e_1, e_2, e_3]$.
Let
$v_1 = [1, 0, 0]$, $v_2 = [0, 1, 0]$, **$v_1 \times v_2 = [0, 0, 1]$ in (1)**.

In coordinate (2): $[f_1, f_2, f_3] = [e_1, e_2, e_3]/2$. So $v_1 = [2, 0, 0]$, $v_2 = [0, 2, 0]$. $v_1 \times v_2 = [0, 0, 4]$ in (2), so **$[0, 0, 2]$ in (1)**.

Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the second cross product still in the original coordinates. You have $e_1\times e_2=e_3$, so
$$
f_1\times f_2=\frac12\,f_3.
$$
That last $1/2$ is the one you are missing.

Comment: Do you mean that cross product depends on the coordinate?

Comment: No. Precisely because it doesn't, you cannot write a vector in one basis and calculate the product with another.